# Convert an Elixir AST to an Erlang AST? Is it possible?

Tags: erlang, abstract-syntax-tree, quote, elixir, beam

Is it possible to take a quoted Elixir expression (AST tree) like this:

```
quote do: 1 + 1
=> {:+, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [1, 1]}
```

And convert it to an Erlang AST?

I looked through the Code module as well as some of the Kernel modules looking for a function that did this but I didn't find anything. I am not even sure if this would be possible... I don't know how things like Elixir macros would be represented in Erlang AST.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't currently a public API to do so. You could look into [the elixir module](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/src/elixir.erl) to know how it is done but it is private API and it can be changed any time with no guarantee of compatibility, or even removed.

Answer (score -1):

For example I wrote 'gist' how it can be done - https://gist.github.com/habibutsu/bc6791d3d81b6ea54e1a

There are used two functions:

```
fun elixir:'string_to_quoted!'/4
fun elixir:quoted_to_erl/3
```